# List declaration error

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Actuall it is not my first time to work with `List`, but I really do not know what is wrong with declaration o the below `List`.

what I want to do is, to declare a `List<Integer, Page>` "Page" is a class I created it, but when I declare my list as shown below I receive the below posted errors

**declaration**:

```
private List<Integer, Page> pageList;
```

**errors**:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Incorrect number of arguments for type List<E>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
 <Integer, Page>
```

Comment: you put only one type of objects in a list, i think you need to look at maps

Comment: How is `Integer` related to the `Page`? What is the range of that `Integer`? Are there gaps between the numbers? Are there duplicates?

Comment: what you are trying to do ?? you are getting error because list is single type

Answer (score 1):

List is a collection of one type, you are passing `Integer` and `Page`. Take a look at `java.util.Map`.

You can have a list of `Page`, declared as `private List<Page> pageList`, but it will only accept `Page` instances, don't know what you want with integers?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about the standard `java.util.List`, this should only have one type argument, not two. If you want a list of `Page` objects, use this:

```
private List<Page> pageList;
```

Answer (score 1):

`List` can only be of one type. So, `List<Integer>` and `List<Page>` are both valid, but `List<Integer, Page>` is not.

Perhaps you want to use a `Map` instead? I'm not sure what you are trying to store, so that is just a guess. Or, you can create a custom class which contains the page and integer, and make the list store those objects of that custom class.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need :

> `private HashMap<Integer, Page> pageList;`

Answer (score 0):

`List` is a collection of things, where as `Map` is a collection of `key-value` pair. I think you are looking for a `key-value` pair, by the look of your try.

Possible declarations

with List : `private List<Integer> pageList` or `private List<Page> pageList`. Here the former is a collection of `Integer Objects` and later a collection of `Page Objects`.

with Map  : `private Map<Integer, Page> pageList` here `Integer` becomes a `Key` and corresponding `Page object` will be a `value`.